# Sum of Columns for multiple variables

Tags: bash, shell, sum, multiple-columns

Using Shell Script (Bash), I am trying to sum the columns for all the different variables of a list. Suppose I have the following input of a Test.tsv file

```
           Win  Lost
Anna        1   1 
Charlotte   3   1
Lauren      5   5
Lauren      6   3
Charlotte   3   2
Charlotte   4   5
Charlotte   2   5
Anna        6   4
Charlotte   2   3
Lauren      3   6
Anna        1   2
Anna        6   2
Lauren      2   1
Lauren      5   5
Lauren      6   6
Charlotte   1   3
Anna        1   4
```

And I want to sum up how much each of the participants have won and lost. So I want to get this as a result:

```
          Sum Win    Sum Lost
Anna        57         58
Charlotte   56         57
Lauren      53         56
```

What I would usually do is take the sum per person and per column and repeat that process over and over. See below how I would do it for the example mentioned:

```
cat Test.tsv | grep -Pi '\bAnna\b' | cut -f2 -d$'\t' |paste -sd+ | bc > Output.tsv
cat Test.tsv | grep -Pi '\bCharlotte\b' | cut -f2 -d$'\t' |paste -sd+ | bc >> Output.tsv
cat Test.tsv | grep -Pi '\bLauren\b' | cut -f2 -d$'\t' |paste -sd+ | bc >> Output.tsv
cat Test.tsv | grep -Pi '\bAnna\b' | cut -f3 -d$'\t' |paste -sd+ | bc > Output.tsv
cat Test.tsv | grep -Pi '\bCharlotte\b' | cut -f3 -d$'\t' |paste -sd+ | bc >> Output.tsv
cat Test.tsv | grep -Pi '\bLauren\b' | cut -f3 -d$'\t' |paste -sd+ | bc >> Output.tsv
```

However I would need to repeat this line for every participant. This becomes a pain when you have to many variables you want to sum it up for.

What would be the way to write this script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with awk. Using GNU awk:

```
 awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR > 1 { won[$1] += $2; lost[$1] += $3 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; print "", "Sum Win", "Sum Lost"; for(p in won) print p, won[p], lost[p] }' filename
```

`-F '\t'` makes awk split lines at tabs, then:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }  # the output should be separated the same way as the input

NR > 1 {            # From the second line forward (skip header)
  won[$1] += $2     # tally up totals
  lost[$1] += $3
}

END {               # When done, print the lot.

  # GNU-specific: Sorted traversal or player names
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"

  print "", "Sum Win", "Sum Lost"
  for(p in won) print p, won[p], lost[p]
}
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use asort ?

Comment: You could use `asorti`, but since that's also GNU-specific it doesn't make much of a difference. Without GNU awk, I'd probably leave the header out of the awk output, print unsorted, pipe through `sort` and add the header afterwards.